# mysql max count within groups

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows

```
id  qNum  opNum
1   1     3
2   1     3
3   1     2
4   1     1
5   2     4
6   2     4
7   2     4
8   2     1
```

I need to get the count grouped by qNum and then opNum, and this is fine to do, but I only want to return the qNum and opNum of the records with the max count in each grouping

So I ideally need a recordset that looks like

```
qNum  opNum  maxCount
1     3      2
2     4      3
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `select count(*) ... group by qnum, opnum`?

Comment: When you say in each group, do you mean in each group of `qNum`?

Comment: I would like the opnum with the most counts, within each qNum

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't look pretty, I think it achieves your desired results:

```
select y.qnum, y.opnum, maxcnt
from (
    select qnum, opnum, count(*) cnt
    from yourtable
    group by qnum, opnum
  ) y
  join (
    select qnum, max(cnt) maxcnt
    from (
      select qnum, opnum, count(*) cnt
      from yourtable
      group by qnum, opnum) t
    group by qnum
    ) t on y.qnum = t.qnum and y.cnt = t.maxcnt
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/031df/3)

Comment: Aaaarrgh! Just noticed a problem with this...if there are two options from a question with the same number of counts, then it returns both options and their counts, but I really only need one, doesn't really matter which one. Can this be incorporated?

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution might be:

```
SELECT qNum, opNum, MAX(temp.maxcount) AS maxcount FROM(
SELECT qNum, opNum, COUNT(*) AS maxCount
FROM t
GROUP BY opNum, qNum ORDER BY maxcount DESC
) AS temp GROUP BY qNum
```

Comment: This can end up with the wrong opnum in the final output

Comment: I fixed it by adding one more grouping